# how to extract data using awk or grep from git log?

Tags: git, bash, shell, awk, grep

I have to extract commit message as well as the corresponding files changed from git log.
Basically, I have BUC IDs given in my commit message. So, for certain set of files I want to get BUC IDs.

Output of my command:    `git log --dirstat`

```
  commit bcc9d8be62b6ac9b8dc02c0bf56d0f433df59466
  Author: 
  Date:   Tue Sep 5 12:08:04 2017 +0530

  BUC:BUC3565-EPIC14 | Review Page Manage permission and junit

 Change-Id: Ice73d25f77d9f6c4afe647e35bdf9ec280dd7dcf

 31.3% manager/src/main/java/com/ericsson/cm/manager/web/listner/
 68.6% manager/src/test/java/com/ericsson/cm/manager/web/listners/

 commit ab70d068b2bcea4060028a3457551cd1cc35a1f1
 Author: 
 Date:   Tue Sep 5 11:30:29 2017 +0530

 BUC:BUC12345 MADE some changes

Change-Id: I7e6733afaf8064c1279e5b217c8d4fba469fd061

  59.0% webui/servermanagement/src/servermanagement/regions/left/
  40.9% webui/servermanagement/src/servermanagement/regions/main/
```

Now I want to get `BUC ID` for only changes made in `webui/`.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: `git log --pretty=%s -- webui/ | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: @ElpieKay Thanks this is working as wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command will delete blank lines from output, filter by `webui` and print `2` lines before the `webui` match.

`git log --dirstat | grep -ve '^$' | grep webui -B 2`

Comment: Thanks a lot @DevDio. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'[: ]' '/BUC/{buc=$3;next}/webui/{print buc;exit}' logfile
BUC12345

# OR
$ awk  '/BUC/{$1=$1;gsub(/BUC:| .*/,"");buc=$0}/webui/{print buc;exit}' logfile
BUC12345
```

Input:

```
$ cat logfile
 commit bcc9d8be62b6ac9b8dc02c0bf56d0f433df59466
  Author: 
  Date:   Tue Sep 5 12:08:04 2017 +0530

  BUC:BUC3565-EPIC14 | Review Page Manage permission and junit

 Change-Id: Ice73d25f77d9f6c4afe647e35bdf9ec280dd7dcf

 31.3% manager/src/main/java/com/ericsson/cm/manager/web/listner/
 68.6% manager/src/test/java/com/ericsson/cm/manager/web/listners/

 commit ab70d068b2bcea4060028a3457551cd1cc35a1f1
 Author: 
 Date:   Tue Sep 5 11:30:29 2017 +0530

 BUC:BUC12345 MADE some changes

Change-Id: I7e6733afaf8064c1279e5b217c8d4fba469fd061

  59.0% webui/servermanagement/src/servermanagement/regions/left/
  40.9% webui/servermanagement/src/servermanagement/regions/main/
```

Comment: Thanks @Akshay Hegde for your response but I find solution provided by other two much easier and better to use.